# Trying to download >3GB file through API using Python/Javascript/cURL

Tags: javascript, python, api, curl, sharefile

I'm trying to download large (large as in anywhere between 3GB - 80GB) files through the ShareFile API to store in a local directory.

I've tried using a Python script, JavaScript, and cURL and all of them fail at one point or another with timeouts.

Below is a snippet of the Python code I'm using, it's not always reliable as it was working one day on a 3GB file and then no longer working the next when there were no changes to the code. It'll just return a 504 timeout. There's no chance it will work on a 10GB file or even 80GB file. I've been researching ways to download large files, but when looking up how to download large files via API call, what's large to other people seem to be MB which I don't have a problem with.

I also tried downloading a range of bytes, but it will timeout when trying to download a 12GB file using the same code below just adding an additional header for Range.

```
def download_item(downloadUrl, token, local_path):
    url = downloadUrl + '/Download'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'}
    response = requests.get(url = url, headers = headers, stream = True)
    print(response.status_code)

    with open(local_path, 'wb') as f:
        print("Opened")
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
            f.write(chunk)
    return print("File completed " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

I've tried using cURL as well which can do the 12GB file I need but times out at anything bigger

There has to be a way to do it with very large files, but my research hasn't returned anything that helps.

Comment: express has a [download](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.download) method you could use. I don't think you can send the entire file, you might have to send it as chunks that are rebuilt while downloading, which I think express does.

Comment: I'll look into this, thank you. Is express able to handle a file of this size though? I see the examples are for .pdf. I suppose I should clarify that these are directories with sub-folders and files. EDIT: I commented before seeing your edits. Will research into this possibility

Comment: I was able to stream a 1GB mp4 file using that. It didn't timeout, you would have to try with a bigger file.

Comment: I had a similar problem, though with uploading. The API you're using may be the older API that cannot handle large files (not sure the limit, but I couldn't even upload 700kb files with it). There's a newer SDK you can use. I recently implemented it via C# with success. https://github.com/citrix/ShareFile-NET (I don't know if there's a Python equivalent).